# nestjs function return <Class1 | Class2>. Cant use items from both classes

Tags: typescript, return, nestjs

```
There are two classes

export class ErrorDto {
  status: string
  message: string
}

export class Data{
  rows: number
  isdeleted: boolean
}

The first function in the service

async getResult(fileId: string): Promise<ErrorDto | Data> {
    const collection = this.db.collection<Data>('myDataCollection');
    try {
      const result = await collection
        .find<Data>(
          { fileId: fileId, isDeleted: false },
          { projection: { _id: 0 } }
        ).toArray();
      return result[0]
    } catch (err) {
      return { status: 'error', message: 'Message error' }
}

The second function in the service use first function
  async deletePaymentFile(body: FileIdDto) {
    const res = await this.getDocFromPaymentsFile(body.fileId)
    if (res.status === 'error') {
        console.log(res.message) 
        // Property 'message' does not exist on type 'ErrorDto | Data'
        // Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Data'
    } else {
        console.log(res.isDeleted)
        // Property 'isDeleted' does not exist on type 'ErrorDto | Data'
        // Property 'isDeleted' does not exist on type 'ErrorDto'
    }
  }

Question: I can access only to res.status but cant access to res.message or res.rows or res.isdeleted
```

If I use only one returned type
async getResult(fileId: string): Promise
I can access to res.status and res.message
or
async getResult(fileId: string): Promise
i can access to res.rows or res.isdeleted

Answer (score 0):

Need to use TypeGuards
Add the same item to both class, for example
type='error' to ErrorDto 
and
type='data' to Data

```
if (res.type === 'error') {
    console.log(res.message) //correct
} else {
    console.log(res.isDeleted) //correct
}
```